# missing part of string - not writing the last letter

Tags: jquery

I want a type effect in jquery.

the problem is, it is not writing the last letter of the string.

'How are you?' will leave the `?`

```
var str = 'how are you?', i = 0, isTag, text;
    (function type() {
    text = str.slice(0, ++i);
    if (text === str) return;
    document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = text;
    var char = text.slice(-1);
    if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
    if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;
    if (isTag) return type();
    setTimeout(type, 100);
    }());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9a8Lbgwc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap the following lines:

```
if (text === str) return;
document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = text;
```

In the last iteration you are existing the function before updating the html content.

Comment: @RickJoe You are very welcome :) Please note that you are not using jQuery, it's vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = text;` is not executed in the last iteration.

```
var str = 'how are you?', i = 0, isTag, text;
    (function type() {
    text = str.slice(0, ++i);

    document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = text;
    if (text === str) return;
    var char = text.slice(-1);
    if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
    if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;
    if (isTag) return type();   

    setTimeout(type, 100);
    }());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
if (text === str) 
    return;
```

Comment: So the function is executed forever?